# How to know with which LiteDB version DB file has been created?

Tags: c#, version, litedb

I am using LiteDB to create db file. but sometime I use LiteDB version 1 and sometime v4. Using any version I am creating same file. So how can I detect that which version of LiteDB was used to create the db file in c# code?
Note: I don't want user version of DB file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have multiple versions of LiteDB as reference to your project no?
How are you instantiating the LiteDB object?

Check that you don't have multiple versions as reference of your project, show us your project references and the places where you are using LiteDB, that might help a bit more.